# ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying (Even though everything is Integer)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

I have a `product` table as follows;

[image]

And the fields are as follows;

[image]

As you can see, aside from `id`, `order_id` is integer and the rest are varchars.

When I execute the following query, it gives me the error that I cannot compare integer and varchar in order_id field.

```
private final static String removeAlternativeProductQuery = "DELETE FROM product where order_id=? AND product_id='?' AND alternative_product_id='?'";

public void removeAlternativeProduct(AlternativeProduct alternativeProduct){

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(removeAlternativeProductQuery);
    query.setParameter(1, (Integer) alternativeProduct.getOrderId());
    query.setParameter(2, alternativeProduct.getProductId());
    query.setParameter(3, alternativeProduct.getAlternativeProductId());
    query.executeUpdate();

}
```

Parallel with the database, `orderId` is Integer and the rest are String in my object. So why am I getting this cast error?

To make it more clear, in the query, `where order_id=?`, the left side is integer. And the right side is taken from

```
query.setParameter(1, (Integer) alternativeProduct.getOrderId());
```

which is also an integer. So where is the character varying error here??

The complete error;

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 54
Error Code: 0
Call: DELETE FROM product where order_id=? AND product_id='?' AND alternative_product_id='?'
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="DELETE FROM product where order_id=? AND product_id='?' AND alternative_product_id='?'")
```

Comment: `product_id='?'` - `'?'` **is**  a string. Remove the single quotes

Comment: But product_id and alternative_product_id are strings. Only order_id is integer. And it points to position :54, which is order_id

Comment: Even if that is a varchar, you don't use quotes around a `?` in a PreparedStatement. (Btw: why are you storing numbers as varchar)?

Comment: Because they are out of integer ranges. They are the product barcodes. I will try removing quotes now.

Comment: It didnt work. Still position 54 gives error. I dont understand. Same query works in PostgreSQL manager tool and removes the row. However in Eclipse it gives error.

Comment: Then I guess your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") sends the parameters as strings not as integers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Quotes are legal for integers. Try: `SELECT 1 = '1'`.

Comment: @FarukYazıcı If you set `log_verbosity = verbose` and `log_statement = all` in `postgresql.conf`, what's the error message from the PostgreSQL logs when running this query?

Comment: @CraigRinger: but still: you can't use them around a placeholder for a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Absolutely right - only as raw literals.